# Alchemy notify slack webhook not working properly

Tags: alchemy

I'm trying to get notifications on an address piped to slack, and Alchemy apparently has a free tool for this, but I can't get the webhook to work. Copied it directly from the slack app, but the tests aren't coming through.
Anybody know why this might be? Or know any (free) services like Alchemy that I could use instead? I know Tenderly works, but the free version is very restricted.